# problem of jstl with spring framework 3

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i am writing following code in my project with spring framework 3

```
<c:set var="s" value="hello"/>
<c:out value="${s}"/>
```

the out put should be hello but its comming `${s}`

when i am running the same code in normal web project with out spring in that the code is working fine

kindly help.....

Comment: what are your versions of everything else? And show the complete jsp.

Comment: removed `spring` tag, since it's not relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out the solution its in the web.xml change the version of webapps in my case i added the version parameter as follow

web-app version='2.5"

solved my problem